# Synchronising feature layer from QField to QGIS that was set to "copy"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qfield, qfieldsync

I want to load points collected in the field with QField into QGIS. For setup I used the QFieldSync Plugin. Unfortunatley, I set the layer action (under QField -> Cable Export) to "copy". When I synchronize now, my feature layers remain empty and I get an error saying:

> QFieldSync: The project you imported does not seem to be an offline
> project

On my smartphone I can see all the data collected in the field.

Is there a workaround to get the data synchronised to QGIS?

I'm using QGIS 2.22, QField 2.1.4, QField Sync 4.1.1

I have found an old post from someone on GitHub having exactly the same problem as I do ([Link](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/590)). Sadly, they didn't come to an conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and must admit, I was a little stupid. Since the last big QField update to 2.0 the actual project is saved on your smartphone under ...\Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield

As an alternative you can export your project directly from the app and won't encounter the issue either.